# Using iMac 2012 as a monitor for MacBook Pro 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, screen

Can I use a Macbook Pro as a monitor for an iMac?

Both of them are on sale from a startup that went out of business, and were originally bought in 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is [Target Display mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3924).

And yes it is compatible with this setup (If they are 2012 machines with Thunderbolt). They must have thunderbolt ports (also work on 27" iMac with Mini Display Port)